# How can I reproduce JQuery's finish() method in JQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

JQuery provides a method (`.finish()`) to end a JQuery method early... does JQuery UI have a method to accomplish the same task? (`.finish()` [does not work](https://jsfiddle.net/zvpt8cy7/).)

Demo HTML:

```
<button id='first'>Fade out / Highlight red</button>
<br>
<button id='second'>Fade in / Snap blue</button>
<br>
<span id='jquery'>JQuery animation</span>
<br>
<span id='jquery-ui'>JQuery UI animation</span>
```

Demo script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#first').click(function (event) {
        $('#jquery').fadeOut(3000);

        $('#jquery-ui').effect('highlight', { color: 'red' }, 3000);
    });

    $('#second').click(function (event) {
        $('#jquery').finish();
        $('#jquery').fadeIn(3000);

        $('#jquery-ui').finish();  // Doesn't seem to do anything.
        $('#jquery-ui').css('background-color', 'blue');
    })
});
```

**Edit:**

While `.stop()` happened to work for my application, and `.stop(true, true)` might work for others, neither answers the original question of whether the same functionality as `.finish()` can be achieved. The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) for `.finish()` describes the subtle difference: in addition to snapping the current animation to its target values, it does the same for all pending animations.

Comment: Like `.stop()`?

Comment: That actually accomplishes what I need, since I'm immediately overriding the only attribute changed in the animation... For some reason I thought I'd need the animation to go to its end state. If someone could still answer that question, it might help someone in the future.

Comment: @MatheusAvellar edited to clarify.

Comment: From the documentation: "It differs (from `.stop()`), however, in that `.finish()` also causes the CSS property of all queued animations to jump to their end values, as well". I see what you mean, you have a valid point.